# Accept() in a thread to avoid "blocking" socket

Tags: c++, sockets, pthreads

I'd like to handle the `accept()` method in a separate thread, to avoid the general freeze while it waits for a connection.

The code (**server only! **):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
  socklen_t clilen;
  char buffer[256];
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
  int n;

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  portno = atoi(argv[1]);
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

  bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

  listen(sockfd,5);
  clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
  newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

  bzero(buffer,256);
  n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);

  n = write(newsockfd,"Message : ",18);

  close(newsockfd);
  close(sockfd);
  return 0; 
}
```

How can I create a separate thread within this code, preventing the `accept()` call to freeze the program. As a bonus, I'd like to handle multiple `accept()` (so the socket does not close itseld after the message is received, but continues to listen and accept requests).

Comment: Umm...in this case, you *want* the `accept()` to block everything else.  Til it returns, you have no client socket to read/write.

Comment: @cHao no, actually I want the `accept()` to run in a separate thread, and have a normal behaviour in this thread.

Comment: If `accept` doesn't block everything til it has accepted a new connection, then `newsockfd` is not valid -- and 2/3 of the lines following it in your example, *are broken*.

Comment: @cHao yes, I cleaned the tests before posting it to make the code understandable.

Comment: By "cleaned", you mean "invalidated".  The code is no longer representative of your problem.  In fact, any answer involving spinning off the `accept` into its own thread (as you're asking for, and claiming is what you really need) would break it.

Comment: @cHao let's assume everything is valid and every call to every function is a success. How can I handle `access()` in a new thread, to prevent the freeze of the main ?

Comment: In your example, *that can not happen*.  The example is so radically different from what you're asking about, as to make it useless.  Make a better one.

Comment: @cHao I really don't understand what's the matter in this code. Everything is just working fine. I only removed the tests (checking if calls return < 0 to throw exception). Again, this code is fine ! And if you're sure that it can't happen with my example, explain me why !

Comment: It can't happen because if you spin off just the `accept` into its own thread, you have no socket to read/write.  (`newsockfd`, and thus any attempt to read/write it, is not a valid socket til `accept` returns.)  If you split the read/write off into the same thread that runs `accept`, then `main` returns immediately, terminating the program before the job's done.  And if you wait for the thread that does the accept/read/write to exit, *you're still blocking* in `main`.

Comment: @cHao actually, if you pay little attention, this code is _only the server_. ;-) And the `accept()` block the thread when called. If you run this code, it waits until a client connects to the socket !

Comment: It works *because* it blocks, currently *because* it's all in one thread.  If you try to separate `accept` from the thread running `main`, without *still* blocking in `main`, the program either tries to read/write an FD it shouldn't or exits immediately without doing anything but opening up a listening socket that then gets instantly closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use select to know if there's a connection waiting that can be accepted, but my approach would be to put all the socket/bind/listen/accept in a thread, put the accept into a loop, and spin off new threads with the connections as they arrive.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I want, but I don't know how to handle posix thread... :/

Comment: Check out the man pages on these APIs... but in short, take all your code above and put it into a Listener function... in main kick off a thread using `pthread_create` and pass in your Listener function.  Do something in main so that it doesn't just immediately exit (like wait for a keyboard character).  Next, put your read/write code in a Handler function.  Put the Listener `accept` in a loop, and use `pthread_create` for new connections, and pass the Handler and the `newsockfd` to it.  Now you've got a multi-threaded connection server.

Comment: plenty of pthreads tutorials on the net (google..). Once you feel comfortable working with it, *then* try to use it in your server.